# How to add the path to an image

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I just started using Umbraco.  I am trying to do a simple thing, but with no luck.

I have an image in the media section:

[image]

and I want to use it here:

```
<img src="<umbraco:Item field='home_SlideImage' runat='server' />" alt="" />
```

field='home_SlideImage':

[image]

If I 'inspect element', I see an id:

[image]

How do I show the actual image, and not the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use umbraco:Item then…

```
<img src="<umbraco:Item field='home_SlideImage' runat='server' xslt='umbraco.library:GetMedia({0},true())/umbracoFile' xsltDisableEscaping='true'></umbraco:Item>" alt=""  />
```

Personally I find it more straight forward and cleaner to do this via a Razor Macro instead...

```
<umbraco:Macro  runat="server" language="cshtml">
    <img src='@Model.MediaById(@Model.home_SlideImage).umbracoFile' alt="" />
</umbraco:Macro>
```

Comment: I have posted another question. maybe you can take a look? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528267/umbraco-title-suffix